# To show all content, svg needs 9000px - Is there a method to force a line break?

Tags: d3.js

I try to do my first project with d3.js - but I got stuck ...

What I want to do:

Depending on the data, rectangles should get a different color. But: There are 187 datapoints, therefore 187 rectangles. To be all shown, my svg needs to have a width of 9000px - a lot of horizontal scrolling ...

Is there a way to kind of get a forced "line break" of the rectangles?

Obviously, increasing height doesn't work.

Comment: Do you mean to say that your rectangles are being drawn left-to-right and thus need 9000 pixels wide, but you need them to be vertically-aligned instead, but you haven't been able to fix it by simply increasing height? I am having a hard time understanding your actual question.

Comment: right, the rectangles are drawn left to right and need all that space. instead, I would like them to be in a new line after, e.g. 1500 px.

Comment: SVG is not like html when it comes to layout and line breaks. Everything is positioned explicitly by setting x and y coordinates. It's impossible to know exactly how your rectangles are positioned, because didn't post any code or create a jsFiddle, but somewhere in your project there's some code that explicitly positions your rectangles (either via `attr("x",...)` of `attr("transform",...)`). You have to modify this code to deliberately start laying things out from a left-most x-position and an incremented y-position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like this might work. I can't be sure without actually seeing your code

```
rectangles
    .attr("x", function(d, i) {return (i % barsPerRow) * barWidth;})
    .attr("y", function(d, i) {return Math.floor(i / barsPerRow) * maxBarHeight;})
;
```

Like @meetamit said, svg does not have an html style layout.